# Pure functional code for the sublists of a list

Tags: functional-programming, common-lisp

The code below gives me the list of sublists of a list. Code can still be improved to avoid the use of `append`, right?

```
(defun sublists (alist)
  (labels ((aux (list p r)
             (if (null list)
                 (append r (maplist #'identity p))
                 (aux (cdr list)
                      (append p (list (car list)))
                      (append r (maplist #'identity p))))))
    (aux alist nil nil)))


CL-USER> (sublists (list 1 2 3 4))
((1) (1 2) (1 2 3) (1 2 3 4) (2) (2 3) (2 3 4) (3) (3 4) (4))
```

ideas?

EDIT: Note that we are really talking about sublists, not about subsets. That is, `(1 2)` is a sublist but `(2 4)` is not a sublist.

Comment: I believe this question is for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Done, I asked in https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/188576/pure-functional-code-for-the-sublists-of-a-list

Answer (score 3):

The return value is a list of length `n*(n-1)/2` of lists of average
length `n/3` thus the algorithm is necessarily asymptotically cubic.

Your algorithm appears to be quartic because you traverse `r` (which
grows as `O(n^3)`) in `append` in cycle.

Thus if you avoid `append` by traversing the list with two pointers and
copying sublists between them, you will eliminate an extra order of
asymptotic complexity.

Interestingly enough, *memory-wise* you are already optimal (IOW, you
cannot replace `append` with `nconc`):

```
(setq *print-circle* t)
(sublists (list 1 2 3 4))
==> ((1) (1 . #1=(2)) #1# (1 . #2=(2 . #3=(3))) 
     #2# #3# 
     (1 . #4=(2 . #5=(3 . #6=(4))))
     #4# #5# #6#)
```

Here is my functional version:

```
(defun sublists-head (list)
  "Return all sublists starting with the 1st element"
  (and list
       (cons (list (first list))
             (mapcar (lambda (sublist)
                       (cons (first list)
                             sublist))
                     (sublists-head (rest list))))))

(defun sublists-3 (list)
  "Return all sublists in a cubic algorithm."
  (mapcon #'sublists-head list))
```

Alas, this loses memory sharing: while the result is the same:

```
(set-exclusive-or (sublists-4 '(1 2 3 4)) (sublists-3 '(1 2 3 4)) :test #'equal)
NIL
```

all sublists returned are fresh.

Comment: You said "Thus if you avoid append by traversing the list with two pointers and copying sublists between them, you will eliminate an extra order of asymptotic complexity.", that is my original question. I would be interested on the actual implementation of that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write the sophisticated code, use "reverse".

```
(defun get-takes (list) (mapcar #'reverse
                                (maplist #'identity (reverse list))))

(defun get-drops (list) (maplist #'identity list))

(defun sublists (list)
  (apply #'append
         (mapcar #'get-drops (get-takes list))))
```

or,

```
(flet ((get-takes (list) (mapcar #'reverse
                                 (maplist #'identity (reverse list))))
       (get-drops (list) (maplist #'identity list)))
  (defun sublists (list)
    (apply #'append (mapcar #'get-drops (get-takes list)))))
```

or, not recommended one,

```
(defun sublists (list)
  (apply #'append
         (mapcar (lambda (list) (maplist #'identity list))
                 (mapcar #'reverse
                         (maplist #'identity (reverse list))))))
```

Comment: APPLY will  impose a length limit > call-arguments-limit .

Comment: Better to move the FLET inside the DEFUN.